# How to get docusign "code" value through php sdk code?

Tags: php, docusignapi

While we run the following code in browser:-
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxxx

We will get "code" value

```
redirect_uri?code=xxxxxxxx
```

We can get AccessCode by this "code" value.

```
$apiClient->generateAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret, $code);
```

But instead of getting this "code" value by browser, can we get this through PHPSDK?
I need a "code" value through php coding.

Answer (score 0):

This "code" is used by the authentication process to obtain the access token. I'm not sure why would you need it. It's a transitional value, it's not very useful. If you are using the SDK - you just need the token to make API requests. Is that not working?

Comment: I am saving the value of access token and refresh token with expiry in json file. But when file not exist then we need that code again to access token, while we transfer docusign to new server...In that time we need to regenerate the token for the first time...I want that code through PHP coding.

Comment: That will not work. The code is only good for 5 minutes. Recommend you save the token and refreshToken to some more persistent storage (like Database or cookie). If don't exist - you have to authenticate again.

Comment: Feel free to email me @ inbar.gazit@docusign.com for specific help to your use-case

Comment: Is there any way to get this done by cron job if doesn't exist or expiry?

Comment: I'm not sure what "this" means? Like I said, this code is not useful. I would need to understand your scenario.

Comment: Ok,so we need to save access_code and refresh code with expiry in database, if server gets changed we need to get code again and generate this credentials..

Comment: that's not how you do it. You save the refresh_token to generate new credentials, not the access code.